# I want to Migrate a Route 53 registered domain and Public hosted zones from one aws account to another across different organization

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to migrate a Route 53 registered domain and public hosted zones from one AWS account to another. Both accounts are managed by separate organisations. Will there be any difficulties in doing so? Can someone advise me on the best way to accomplish this?

I have a proper plan in place to move a domain and host zone from one AWS account to another. But the issue here is that we recently made a few changes to our AWS accounts. As a result, the source and destination accounts are now managed by separate organisations. Because the accounts are in different organisations, I'm unsure whether to continue with my original strategy or not. Before beginning, I want to make certain that there will be no obstacles or problems.

Answer (score 1):

Simple recreate the hosted zone in the second AWS account, then point the domain registrar at the name servers for the second AWS account. If things go wrong point the registrar back at the first AWS account

Complications may occur if you use alias records.